# Create one .proto file from several

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We have been using `Serializer.GetProto<T>()` to generate proto-definitions for a dozen or so messages. We would like to combine all of the definitions into one .proto file to make it easier to see what messages we are sending. However I cannot find a way of merging the outputs. The biggest problem is when one POCO is used in multiple messages (like `Person` in the example below). Is there a way of merging several .proto definitions into a single definition?

Or is `Serializer.GetProto<T>()` the wrong tool to use for this job and something else already does this?

Using protobuf-net v2.0.0.668.

---

Minimal example (summary: classes `Department` and `Order` both contain class `Person`, generate proto definition for both `Department` and `Order`):

```
class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string departmentProto = Serializer.GetProto<Department>();
    string orderProto = Serializer.GetProto<Order>();

    Console.WriteLine(departmentProto);
    Console.WriteLine(orderProto);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
  [DataMember(Order = 1)]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Order = 2)]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Department
{
  [DataMember(Order = 1)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Order = 2)]
  public Person[] Employees { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Order
{
  [DataMember(Order = 1)]
  public string ItemOrdered { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Order = 2)]
  public Person Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Actual output:

```
package ConsoleApplication1;
message Department {
  optional string Name = 1;
  repeated Person Employees = 2;
}
message Person {
  optional string FirstName = 1;
  repeated string LastName = 2;
}

package ConsoleApplication1;
message Order {
  optional string ItemOrdered = 1;
  repeated Person Customer = 2;
}
message Person {                  <-- Person is repeated
  optional string FirstName = 1;
  repeated string LastName = 2;
}
```

Desired output:

```
package ConsoleApplication1;
message Department {
  optional string Name = 1;
  repeated Person Employees = 2;
}
message Order {
  optional string ItemOrdered = 1;
  repeated Person Customer = 2;
}
message Person {                  <-- Person only appears once
  optional string FirstName = 1;
  repeated string LastName = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetProto()` assumes that your model will have a single root type that touches everything you need. If you don't have that, you could *invent* a fake type that has all the types you care about as properties. Even if you don't ever use it, you could use that type in `GetProto()` to get a composite model file. Not ideal, but the other options are:

- merge by hand
- change the code

Comment: Is it still the case in 2017?

Comment: @Evk yes; the .proto emit code has been updated to deal with proto3, but the API still currently takes a single type as the primary input; I *guess* it probably wouldn't be to hard to add an overload that takes an array, though - IIRC it basically works as a queue, so if I enqueue multiple types at the start it would *probably* get the right output

Comment: Yes that would be really great. I have exactly the same use case (a lot of messages for which I need to generate .proto file for javascript consumers) and I think it's not that uncommon (and even more common than generting .proto from a single root).